# Integrate OneLogin OIDC with react native mobile app

Tags: android, react-native, single-sign-on, openid-connect, onelogin

I've been trying to integrate one of our company mobile app(react native) with Octa and Onelogin with Open ID connect. I could be able to integrate Octa with using the react-native-app-auth library and AppAuth SDK(Android, iOS). But still, I could not find a way to integrate with the Onelogin. Does anyone has experience with Onelogin integration with mobile apps?

Comment: Did you manage to integrate SSO with React Native?